# Bidirectional level shifter circuit problem

Tags: level-shifting, bidirectional

Ok, so here is my problem:

I am trying to create a small 3.3V to 5V signal level shifter, using a BSS138 transistor.
This is my source for the circuit: a [SparkFun circuit](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Level-Converter-v10.pdf).

This is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

As you can see, I have one bidirectional and one unidirectional line. On the left is the `Low Voltage` (3.3V) part and the right is the `High Voltage` (5V) one. When I connect the `TX_LV` to the `Gnd` line, the `TX_HV` turns to 0V. When I connect the `TX_HV` to `Gnd`, it does happen on the other side as well.

But the `BSS138` transistor seems to act as a 20kohm resistor when closed (I even measured it with my multimeter - it was about 19.7kohms). This results in approximately 4.1V on both the `LV` (Low Voltage) and `TX_LV` lines (which should be 3.3V) when 5V is applied to the `HV` input and neither `TX_LV` and `TX_HV` are connected to `Gnd`...

This is quite a problem as I want to connect a Raspberry Pi to an Arduino via Serial port and I don't want to damage my Raspberry Pi by putting 4.1V on its pins. Could anyone please tell me how to fix this or what could I use instead of this solution?

Comment: You need to connect LV to a 3.3V source for the circuit to work properly.

Comment: That is properly connected, but thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: Oh my god I rechecked (not that I didn't recheck like 50 times before) and I had one connection a bit loose, so you were right after all - the 3.3V source was disconnecter. Could you post that as an answer so I can accept it? You did actually help me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect LV to a 3.3V source for the circuit to work properly. If it's floating up to 4.1V, it must not be connected to anything.